# When Applying android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" to <application> in AndroidManifest.xml removes ActionBar

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm adding a `CoordinatorLayout` to my `MainActivity` and when I set the`Theme` of my app to `Theme.AppCompat` it removes the `ActionBar` entirely from my app. What is the reason for this and how can I prevent this from happening?

Do I need to define a `custom action bar`? It seems that every time I fiddle with Themes I just break my apps over and over again and at this point in development I'm not trying to put lipstick on the pig.

Here's where I apply my theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="DSA.iStock" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.2" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_PRINT_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application 
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

*NOTE: This project is a Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: Please add `Theme.AppCompat` xml code to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your `Theme.AppCompat` in your `style folder` if you have added

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

**Please make this to as `true` as follow.**

```
<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
```

**Hope this will help**

Comment: So, I have not added anything references `styles.xml`. From your answer I'm assuming this is a requirement or I just get what the theme is defaulted to?

Comment: You are using `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` please check your `style .xml` there will be a `Theme.AppCompat` theme. under the theme you  need to confirm `windowActionBar` set as `true`

Comment: Or you can also create custom theme to show  `Action Bar` under `style.xml`. Like as  
  `<style name="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerIconStyle</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>

    </style>`